# How to retain object returned from Eve restful framework

Tags: eve

I am new to Eve restful framework and I have written some code that works as intended. Despite the success, I am unable to understand what happens to an object returned by the API.

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import BasicAuth
class MyBasicAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource,
                   method):
        customers = app.data.driver.db['customer']
        customer = customers.find_one({'username': username})
        return customer and \
                customer['password'] == password

app = Eve(auth=MyBasicAuth)
```

As you can see in my code, `check_auth` returns a customer object along with a boolean. Can someone please explain this and also if it is possible to receive this information on client end.

Comment: This is just an authentication class used by the framework, it is used internally to validate BasicAuth credentials. Have you checked the [quickstart](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html) example?

Comment: hi thanks for your response. Yes i have checked it.  Wondering more of what happens to any variable returned in the method?

Comment: In this example the returned boolean will be used by the application to allow or not any app request using default authentication. Notice `MyBasicAuth` passed as a parameter in the app initialization. It is not a resource accessible by the user.
To retrieve, or post customers, you should user other resource endpoints available in you [domain configuration](http://python-eve.org/config.html#domain-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your response once again, It seems much more clearer to me now. I'm assuming that the information returned from the methods are consumed and used by or within the framework.

Comment: Yes, this `check_auth` function being from an authentication class specifically, it will be used by the framework. There are ways to make your own [flask blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/) functions with custom logic, since eve is a flask app.

Comment: OK, got it. I highly appreciate the help.